# Find minimum of the $a+c+e$ if $a+b+c+d+e=100$.

Tags: inequality, optimization

> Let $a\ge b\ge c \ge d \ge e \ge0$ and $a+b+c+d+e=100$. Find minimum of
> $$a+c+e$$

#### My work so far:

$100=a+b+c+d+e\le 5a \Rightarrow a\ge20$

I think that $a+c+e \ge 50$ (if $a=40,b=40,c=10,d=10,e=0$ or $a=b=49, c=d=e=1$).

Comment: Is it being solved over the natural numbers?

Comment: Note tat $49+1+1+1+1\ne 100.$

Comment: @mfl: I edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$100=a+b+c+d+e\le a+a+c+c+e=2a+2c+2e-e.$$ Thus $$50\le 50+\frac e2\le a+c+e.$$ So, the minimum of $a+c+e$ is $50$ and is achieved if $e=0.$

Comment: 50,50,0,0,0 will also give the same result.

Comment: It takes more than $e=0$ to get $a+c+e$ down to $50$  because your inequalities could be strict.  You could have $100,0,0,0,0$, for example.  But a good approach that shows $50$ is the minimum and that you must have $e=0$ to achieve it.